# Why does this KML line not get plotted in the right place?

Tags: google-maps, gis, kml

I have the following list of co ordinates which represent points on a race track in Argentina:

```
-34.6945568333,-58.4617525000
-34.6937816667,-58.4611296667
-34.6927506667,-58.4602933333
-34.6919313333,-58.4596181667
-34.6917445000,-58.4594528333
-34.6916251667,-58.4593376667
-34.6914956667,-58.4591936667
-34.6914396667,-58.4591050000
-34.6914105000,-58.4590106667
-34.6913923333,-58.4588921667
-34.6914015000,-58.4587473333
-34.6914261667,-58.4586343333
-34.6914796667,-58.4585265000
-34.6915693333,-58.4584185000
-34.6916373333,-58.4583646667
-34.6916901667,-58.4583301667
-34.6917491667,-58.4583063333
-34.6918041667,-58.4582841667
-34.6918608333,-58.4582746667
-34.6919396667,-58.4582666667
-34.6928048333,-58.4582771667
-34.6928768333,-58.4582876667
-34.6929505000,-58.4583120000
-34.6930225000,-58.4583433333
-34.6930853333,-58.4583778333
-34.6931520000,-58.4584276667
-34.6932040000,-58.4584808333
-34.6932598333,-58.4585453333
-34.6945025000,-58.4599683333
-34.6945350000,-58.4599993333
-34.6945928333,-58.4600505000
-34.6946528333,-58.4600996667
-34.6947195000,-58.4601380000
-34.6947881667,-58.4601653333
-34.6948526667,-58.4601840000
-34.6949186667,-58.4601955000
-34.6949826667,-58.4602033333
-34.6950525000,-58.4602020000
-34.6951175000,-58.4601931667
-34.6952093333,-58.4601805000
-34.6952813333,-58.4601541667
-34.6953335000,-58.4601210000
-34.6953875000,-58.4600991667
-34.6954435000,-58.4600853333
-34.6954905000,-58.4600741667
-34.6955533333,-58.4600643333
-34.6955988333,-58.4600620000
-34.6956410000,-58.4600636667
-34.6956896667,-58.4600720000
-34.6957236667,-58.4600801667
-34.6957648333,-58.4600911667
-34.6958080000,-58.4601096667
-34.6958490000,-58.4601281667
-34.6958886667,-58.4601478333
-34.6959131667,-58.4601665000
-34.6959395000,-58.4601846667
-34.6959630000,-58.4602008333
-34.6959893333,-58.4602223333
-34.6960228333,-58.4602616667
-34.6960723333,-58.4603421667
-34.6963300000,-58.4609398333
-34.6964455000,-58.4612141667
-34.6968348333,-58.4621026667
-34.6968750000,-58.4621861667
-34.6969111667,-58.4622451667
-34.6969395000,-58.4622790000
-34.6969748333,-58.4623220000
-34.6970081667,-58.4623608333
-34.6970478333,-58.4624038333
-34.6970868333,-58.4624405000
-34.6971185000,-58.4624616667
-34.6971495000,-58.4624875000
-34.6971816667,-58.4625126667
-34.6972235000,-58.4625415000
-34.6972638333,-58.4625618333
-34.6972895000,-58.4625775000
-34.6973166667,-58.4625865000
-34.6973530000,-58.4625993333
-34.6974033333,-58.4626093333
-34.6974508333,-58.4626175000
-34.6974996667,-58.4626353333
-34.6975511667,-58.4626636667
-34.6975961667,-58.4627015000
-34.6976378333,-58.4627336667
-34.6976781667,-58.4627693333
-34.6977185000,-58.4628120000
-34.6977568333,-58.4628555000
-34.6977936667,-58.4629023333
-34.6978226667,-58.4629361667
-34.6978736667,-58.4630083333
-34.6978993333,-58.4630453333
-34.6979233333,-58.4630895000
-34.6979466667,-58.4631253333
-34.6979625000,-58.4631583333
-34.6979760000,-58.4631895000
-34.6979833333,-58.4632201667
-34.6979940000,-58.4632636667
-34.6980465000,-58.4636665000
-34.6981476667,-58.4646958333
-34.6981735000,-58.4649426667
-34.6981808333,-58.4650676667
-34.6981753333,-58.4651311667
-34.6981590000,-58.4651718333
-34.6981308333,-58.4652238333
-34.6980881667,-58.4652741667
-34.6980388333,-58.4653150000
-34.6979670000,-58.4653526667
-34.6979028333,-58.4653743333
-34.6978278333,-58.4653861667
-34.6977618333,-58.4653810000
-34.6976986667,-58.4653615000
-34.6976215000,-58.4653241667
-34.6975831667,-58.4652850000
-34.6975418333,-58.4652193333
-34.6974978333,-58.4651235000
-34.6971001667,-58.4642565000
-34.6968883333,-58.4638256667
-34.6968026667,-58.4636791667
-34.6967640000,-58.4636213333
-34.6967306667,-58.4635715000
-34.6966910000,-58.4635233333
-34.6966361667,-58.4634598333
-34.6965351667,-58.4633501667
-34.6963385000,-58.4631675000
-34.6960658333,-58.4629495000
-34.6956288333,-58.4626021667
-34.6949101667,-58.4620285000
-34.6945568333,-58.4617525000
-34.6946273333,-58.4616173333
-34.6939660000,-58.4610935000
-34.6936028333,-58.4607920000
-34.6930496667,-58.4603410000
-34.6922991667,-58.4597328333
-34.6921435000,-58.4596025000
-34.6919128333,-58.4594071667
-34.6917100000,-58.4592101667
-34.6915841667,-58.4590801667
-34.6915508333,-58.4590360000
-34.6915288333,-58.4589750000
-34.6915191667,-58.4589360000
-34.6915210000,-58.4588640000
-34.6915340000,-58.4587863333
-34.6915543333,-58.4587286667
-34.6915943333,-58.4586430000
-34.6916503333,-58.4585826667
-34.6916950000,-58.4585230000
-34.6917410000,-58.4584835000
-34.6917918333,-58.4584558333
-34.6918343333,-58.4584366667
-34.6919016667,-58.4584201667
-34.6920376667,-58.4584195000
-34.6927725000,-58.4584046667
-34.6928358333,-58.4584218333
-34.6928948333,-58.4584391667
-34.6929450000,-58.4584615000
-34.6930038333,-58.4584941667
-34.6930550000,-58.4585265000
-34.6930948333,-58.4585520000
-34.6931651667,-58.4586141667
-34.6939556667,-58.4594970000
-34.6944235000,-58.4600325000
-34.6944631667,-58.4600801667
-34.6945460000,-58.4601543333
-34.6946138333,-58.4601991667
-34.6946736667,-58.4602415000
-34.6947151667,-58.4602643333
-34.6947580000,-58.4602826667
-34.6948048333,-58.4603010000
-34.6948468333,-58.4603116667
-34.6949060000,-58.4603253333
-34.6949548333,-58.4603275000
-34.6950148333,-58.4603258333
-34.6950811667,-58.4603196667
-34.6951413333,-58.4603135000
-34.6951998333,-58.4603061667
-34.6952628333,-58.4602920000
-34.6953158333,-58.4602698333
-34.6953563333,-58.4602453333
-34.6953918333,-58.4602288333
-34.6954393333,-58.4602091667
-34.6954798333,-58.4601966667
-34.6955243333,-58.4601881667
-34.6955553333,-58.4601840000
-34.6955956667,-58.4601798333
-34.6956378333,-58.4601780000
-34.6956778333,-58.4601863333
-34.6957278333,-58.4602015000
-34.6957656667,-58.4602175000
-34.6958156667,-58.4602365000
-34.6958611667,-58.4602616667
-34.6959073333,-58.4602946667
-34.6959483333,-58.4603356667
-34.6960186667,-58.4604748333
-34.6963766667,-58.4612961667
-34.6967138333,-58.4620723333
-34.6967810000,-58.4622233333
-34.6968550000,-58.4623410000
-34.6969251667,-58.4624230000
-34.6969883333,-58.4624945000
-34.6970673333,-58.4625701667
-34.6971511667,-58.4626305000
-34.6972196667,-58.4626591667
-34.6972821667,-58.4626853333
-34.6973280000,-58.4627080000
-34.6973861667,-58.4627268333
-34.6974296667,-58.4627426667
-34.6974721667,-58.4627663333
-34.6975101667,-58.4627883333
-34.6975513333,-58.4628140000
-34.6975866667,-58.4628401667
-34.6976331667,-58.4628838333
-34.6976733333,-58.4629235000
-34.6977301667,-58.4629798333
-34.6977730000,-58.4630395000
-34.6978126667,-58.4631008333
-34.6978573333,-58.4631875000
-34.6978833333,-58.4632413333
-34.6979061667,-58.4632945000
-34.6979153333,-58.4633293333
-34.6979198333,-58.4633711667
-34.6980378333,-58.4645131667
-34.6980725000,-58.4648936667
-34.6980745000,-58.4649675000
-34.6980630000,-58.4650288333
-34.6980431667,-58.4650736667
-34.6980200000,-58.4651121667
-34.6979915000,-58.4651533333
-34.6979418333,-58.4651920000
-34.6978868333,-58.4652090000
-34.6978346667,-58.4652146667
-34.6977905000,-58.4652035000
-34.6977355000,-58.4651820000
-34.6976850000,-58.4651381667
-34.6976455000,-58.4650911667
-34.6976105000,-58.4650260000
-34.6974658333,-58.4647318333
-34.6971325000,-58.4640488333
-34.6969758333,-58.4637458333
-34.6969576667,-58.4637085000
-34.6969376667,-58.4636713333
-34.6968960000,-58.4636110000
-34.6968455000,-58.4635383333
-34.6967965000,-58.4634545000
-34.6967340000,-58.4633766667
-34.6965396667,-58.4631556667
-34.6964680000,-58.4630938333
-34.6961701667,-58.4628421667
-34.6955260000,-58.4623258333
-34.6949825000,-58.4618956667
-34.6946275000,-58.4616175000
```

If you take any one of these lat and long locations and put it into google maps the marker comes up in the right place on the track. However when I then try and convert this into a KML overlay the shape seems to be correct but it plots it in the middle of the sea somewhere!

Here is the KML I am generating from these coordinates (I am using http://display-kml.appspot.com to test the KML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Track</name>
    <description>A track in Argentina</description>
    <Style id="yellowLineGreenPoly">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>7f00ffff</color>
        <width>4</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Track</name>
      <description>Track</description>
      <styleUrl>#yellowLineGreenPoly</styleUrl>
      <LineString>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>
            -34.6945568333,-58.4617525000
            -34.6937816667,-58.4611296667
            -34.6927506667,-58.4602933333
            -34.6919313333,-58.4596181667
            -34.6917445000,-58.4594528333
            -34.6916251667,-58.4593376667
            -34.6914956667,-58.4591936667
            -34.6914396667,-58.4591050000
            -34.6914105000,-58.4590106667
            -34.6913923333,-58.4588921667
            -34.6914015000,-58.4587473333
            -34.6914261667,-58.4586343333
            -34.6914796667,-58.4585265000
            -34.6915693333,-58.4584185000
            -34.6916373333,-58.4583646667
            -34.6916901667,-58.4583301667
            -34.6917491667,-58.4583063333
            -34.6918041667,-58.4582841667
            -34.6918608333,-58.4582746667
            -34.6919396667,-58.4582666667
            -34.6928048333,-58.4582771667
            -34.6928768333,-58.4582876667
            -34.6929505000,-58.4583120000
            -34.6930225000,-58.4583433333
            -34.6930853333,-58.4583778333
            -34.6931520000,-58.4584276667
            -34.6932040000,-58.4584808333
            -34.6932598333,-58.4585453333
            -34.6945025000,-58.4599683333
            -34.6945350000,-58.4599993333
            -34.6945928333,-58.4600505000
            -34.6946528333,-58.4600996667
            -34.6947195000,-58.4601380000
            -34.6947881667,-58.4601653333
            -34.6948526667,-58.4601840000
            -34.6949186667,-58.4601955000
            -34.6949826667,-58.4602033333
            -34.6950525000,-58.4602020000
            -34.6951175000,-58.4601931667
            -34.6952093333,-58.4601805000
            -34.6952813333,-58.4601541667
            -34.6953335000,-58.4601210000
            -34.6953875000,-58.4600991667
            -34.6954435000,-58.4600853333
            -34.6954905000,-58.4600741667
            -34.6955533333,-58.4600643333
            -34.6955988333,-58.4600620000
            -34.6956410000,-58.4600636667
            -34.6956896667,-58.4600720000
            -34.6957236667,-58.4600801667
            -34.6957648333,-58.4600911667
            -34.6958080000,-58.4601096667
            -34.6958490000,-58.4601281667
            -34.6958886667,-58.4601478333
            -34.6959131667,-58.4601665000
            -34.6959395000,-58.4601846667
            -34.6959630000,-58.4602008333
            -34.6959893333,-58.4602223333
            -34.6960228333,-58.4602616667
            -34.6960723333,-58.4603421667
            -34.6963300000,-58.4609398333
            -34.6964455000,-58.4612141667
            -34.6968348333,-58.4621026667
            -34.6968750000,-58.4621861667
            -34.6969111667,-58.4622451667
            -34.6969395000,-58.4622790000
            -34.6969748333,-58.4623220000
            -34.6970081667,-58.4623608333
            -34.6970478333,-58.4624038333
            -34.6970868333,-58.4624405000
            -34.6971185000,-58.4624616667
            -34.6971495000,-58.4624875000
            -34.6971816667,-58.4625126667
            -34.6972235000,-58.4625415000
            -34.6972638333,-58.4625618333
            -34.6972895000,-58.4625775000
            -34.6973166667,-58.4625865000
            -34.6973530000,-58.4625993333
            -34.6974033333,-58.4626093333
            -34.6974508333,-58.4626175000
            -34.6974996667,-58.4626353333
            -34.6975511667,-58.4626636667
            -34.6975961667,-58.4627015000
            -34.6976378333,-58.4627336667
            -34.6976781667,-58.4627693333
            -34.6977185000,-58.4628120000
            -34.6977568333,-58.4628555000
            -34.6977936667,-58.4629023333
            -34.6978226667,-58.4629361667
            -34.6978736667,-58.4630083333
            -34.6978993333,-58.4630453333
            -34.6979233333,-58.4630895000
            -34.6979466667,-58.4631253333
            -34.6979625000,-58.4631583333
            -34.6979760000,-58.4631895000
            -34.6979833333,-58.4632201667
            -34.6979940000,-58.4632636667
            -34.6980465000,-58.4636665000
            -34.6981476667,-58.4646958333
            -34.6981735000,-58.4649426667
            -34.6981808333,-58.4650676667
            -34.6981753333,-58.4651311667
            -34.6981590000,-58.4651718333
            -34.6981308333,-58.4652238333
            -34.6980881667,-58.4652741667
            -34.6980388333,-58.4653150000
            -34.6979670000,-58.4653526667
            -34.6979028333,-58.4653743333
            -34.6978278333,-58.4653861667
            -34.6977618333,-58.4653810000
            -34.6976986667,-58.4653615000
            -34.6976215000,-58.4653241667
            -34.6975831667,-58.4652850000
            -34.6975418333,-58.4652193333
            -34.6974978333,-58.4651235000
            -34.6971001667,-58.4642565000
            -34.6968883333,-58.4638256667
            -34.6968026667,-58.4636791667
            -34.6967640000,-58.4636213333
            -34.6967306667,-58.4635715000
            -34.6966910000,-58.4635233333
            -34.6966361667,-58.4634598333
            -34.6965351667,-58.4633501667
            -34.6963385000,-58.4631675000
            -34.6960658333,-58.4629495000
            -34.6956288333,-58.4626021667
            -34.6949101667,-58.4620285000
            -34.6945568333,-58.4617525000
            -34.6946273333,-58.4616173333
            -34.6939660000,-58.4610935000
            -34.6936028333,-58.4607920000
            -34.6930496667,-58.4603410000
            -34.6922991667,-58.4597328333
            -34.6921435000,-58.4596025000
            -34.6919128333,-58.4594071667
            -34.6917100000,-58.4592101667
            -34.6915841667,-58.4590801667
            -34.6915508333,-58.4590360000
            -34.6915288333,-58.4589750000
            -34.6915191667,-58.4589360000
            -34.6915210000,-58.4588640000
            -34.6915340000,-58.4587863333
            -34.6915543333,-58.4587286667
            -34.6915943333,-58.4586430000
            -34.6916503333,-58.4585826667
            -34.6916950000,-58.4585230000
            -34.6917410000,-58.4584835000
            -34.6917918333,-58.4584558333
            -34.6918343333,-58.4584366667
            -34.6919016667,-58.4584201667
            -34.6920376667,-58.4584195000
            -34.6927725000,-58.4584046667
            -34.6928358333,-58.4584218333
            -34.6928948333,-58.4584391667
            -34.6929450000,-58.4584615000
            -34.6930038333,-58.4584941667
            -34.6930550000,-58.4585265000
            -34.6930948333,-58.4585520000
            -34.6931651667,-58.4586141667
            -34.6939556667,-58.4594970000
            -34.6944235000,-58.4600325000
            -34.6944631667,-58.4600801667
            -34.6945460000,-58.4601543333
            -34.6946138333,-58.4601991667
            -34.6946736667,-58.4602415000
            -34.6947151667,-58.4602643333
            -34.6947580000,-58.4602826667
            -34.6948048333,-58.4603010000
            -34.6948468333,-58.4603116667
            -34.6949060000,-58.4603253333
            -34.6949548333,-58.4603275000
            -34.6950148333,-58.4603258333
            -34.6950811667,-58.4603196667
            -34.6951413333,-58.4603135000
            -34.6951998333,-58.4603061667
            -34.6952628333,-58.4602920000
            -34.6953158333,-58.4602698333
            -34.6953563333,-58.4602453333
            -34.6953918333,-58.4602288333
            -34.6954393333,-58.4602091667
            -34.6954798333,-58.4601966667
            -34.6955243333,-58.4601881667
            -34.6955553333,-58.4601840000
            -34.6955956667,-58.4601798333
            -34.6956378333,-58.4601780000
            -34.6956778333,-58.4601863333
            -34.6957278333,-58.4602015000
            -34.6957656667,-58.4602175000
            -34.6958156667,-58.4602365000
            -34.6958611667,-58.4602616667
            -34.6959073333,-58.4602946667
            -34.6959483333,-58.4603356667
            -34.6960186667,-58.4604748333
            -34.6963766667,-58.4612961667
            -34.6967138333,-58.4620723333
            -34.6967810000,-58.4622233333
            -34.6968550000,-58.4623410000
            -34.6969251667,-58.4624230000
            -34.6969883333,-58.4624945000
            -34.6970673333,-58.4625701667
            -34.6971511667,-58.4626305000
            -34.6972196667,-58.4626591667
            -34.6972821667,-58.4626853333
            -34.6973280000,-58.4627080000
            -34.6973861667,-58.4627268333
            -34.6974296667,-58.4627426667
            -34.6974721667,-58.4627663333
            -34.6975101667,-58.4627883333
            -34.6975513333,-58.4628140000
            -34.6975866667,-58.4628401667
            -34.6976331667,-58.4628838333
            -34.6976733333,-58.4629235000
            -34.6977301667,-58.4629798333
            -34.6977730000,-58.4630395000
            -34.6978126667,-58.4631008333
            -34.6978573333,-58.4631875000
            -34.6978833333,-58.4632413333
            -34.6979061667,-58.4632945000
            -34.6979153333,-58.4633293333
            -34.6979198333,-58.4633711667
            -34.6980378333,-58.4645131667
            -34.6980725000,-58.4648936667
            -34.6980745000,-58.4649675000
            -34.6980630000,-58.4650288333
            -34.6980431667,-58.4650736667
            -34.6980200000,-58.4651121667
            -34.6979915000,-58.4651533333
            -34.6979418333,-58.4651920000
            -34.6978868333,-58.4652090000
            -34.6978346667,-58.4652146667
            -34.6977905000,-58.4652035000
            -34.6977355000,-58.4651820000
            -34.6976850000,-58.4651381667
            -34.6976455000,-58.4650911667
            -34.6976105000,-58.4650260000
            -34.6974658333,-58.4647318333
            -34.6971325000,-58.4640488333
            -34.6969758333,-58.4637458333
            -34.6969576667,-58.4637085000
            -34.6969376667,-58.4636713333
            -34.6968960000,-58.4636110000
            -34.6968455000,-58.4635383333
            -34.6967965000,-58.4634545000
            -34.6967340000,-58.4633766667
            -34.6965396667,-58.4631556667
            -34.6964680000,-58.4630938333
            -34.6961701667,-58.4628421667
            -34.6955260000,-58.4623258333
            -34.6949825000,-58.4618956667
            -34.6946275000,-58.4616175000

        </coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because in my KML i was displaying the points lat/long and they should be long/lat